# Auto start compton in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, intel, compton

*Sorry for my bad English*
My problem is screen tearing in Lubuntu 16.04, my GPU is Intel HD graphic
I install compton and this command help me
`$ compton -b --vsync opengl`
But I want to auto start compton so I search the Internet for this.
I edit the file 
`/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` by adding this line `@compton -b --vsync opengl`
But it do not work, can anyone help me?

```
$ which compton
/usr/bin/compton

$ sudo systemctl status mycompton.service
● mycompton.service - compton autostart script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mycompton.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since T5 2017-09-07 15:59:44 ICT; 5s ago
  Process: 6342 ExecStart=/usr/bin/compton -b --vsync opengl (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: Failed to start compton autostart script.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Unit entered failed state.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: Stopped compton autostart script.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: Failed to start compton autostart script.

$ journalctl -xe
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mycompton.service has finished shutting down.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: Starting compton autostart script...
-- Subject: Unit mycompton.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mycompton.service has begun starting up.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon compton[6342]: session_init(): Can't open display.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: Failed to start compton autostart script.
-- Subject: Unit mycompton.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mycompton.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Unit entered failed state.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: Stopped compton autostart script.
-- Subject: Unit mycompton.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mycompton.service has finished shutting down.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Th09 07 15:59:44 GaCon systemd[1]: Failed to start compton autostart script.
-- Subject: Unit mycompton.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mycompton.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Th09 07 15:59:50 GaCon sudo[6344]:      lhv : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/lhv ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status mycompton.service
Th09 07 15:59:50 GaCon sudo[6344]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Th09 07 15:59:50 GaCon sudo[6344]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Th09 07 16:00:14 GaCon com.canonical.indicator.application[974]: (process:1199): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Application already exists, re-requesting pro
lines 2628-2669/2669 (END)
```

Comment: Please run `which compton` and post the result into your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `systemd` service to autostart it:

1. Create a service file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mycompton.service
   ```
2. Add the following configurations:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=compton autostart script
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Type=forking
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/compton -b --vsync opengl
   Restart=always

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
3. Start and enable the compton service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start mycompton
   sudo systemctl enable mycompton
   ```
4. Check the status:

   ```
   systemctl status mycompton
   ```
5. Stop it with:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop mycompton
   ```

**Note:**

Replace the line `/usr/bin/coompton` with the result of `which compton`, if different from my own entry.

Comment: `$ sudo systemctl start mycompton
Job for mycompton.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mycompton.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
`

Comment: This is result for `sudo systemctl status mycompton.service
` `Th09 07 15:46:55 GaCon systemd[1]: Failed to start compton autostart script.
Th09 07 15:46:55 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Unit entered failed state.
Th09 07 15:46:55 GaCon systemd[1]: mycompton.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`

Comment: `● mycompton.service - compton autostart script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mycompton.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since T5 2017-09-07 15:46:55 ICT; 3min 4s ago
  Process: 5814 ExecStart=/usr/bin/compton -b --vsync opengl (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
`

Comment: Is this `/usr/bin/compton` the result of `which compton`? And run `journalctl -xe` and paste the result into your question. Put all into your question not the comments